# What does it mean when a name is very interesting to you

Tags: american-english

I just wanted to know out of curiosity because I just wanted to know what an interesting name means

Comment: The meaning of the adjective interesting is available in dictionaries. It's not clear what you are exactly asking. If you're asking what makes insteresting a name to someone, the provided answers would be opinion-based and this question may be closed.

Comment: @RubioRic I disagree. Especially in the US, but probably in other places, the word "interesting" can be used with unexpected meanings like "strange" and have a negative connotation, depending on the speaker's intent. This can be confusing to speakers of languages where "interesting" just means "being of/provoking interest". What the original poster could've perhaps done a little better is set the context for the question, e.g. he/she being the object of a remark like "you have an interesting name". Then the question really becomes "why would people say that? I don't see what's so interesting"

Comment: @RuslanD As per the rules in the help center, askers are required to post what research they have done to solve their problem. This includes simple google searches, dictionary definitions they have looked at, and what they believe to be the intended meaning of a word/phrase/sentence. While you are right about that particular phrase having a negative connotation, the original post says nothing about that and shows no research effort. As you say, it also does not give us specific context. Such questions if not edited are usually closed.

Comment: @RuslanD Unexpected? Interesting: arousing curiosity or interest; holding or catching the attention. I think that when somebody finds something strange or unique it's because that something has catched his attention somehow. Your explanation does not differ significantly from the definition.

Comment: @RuslanD Also kindly see [DO NOT FEED THE BEARS](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/do-not-feed-the-bears) and several other related questions in Meta. - This is perhaps well reflected in the fact that OP has posted a second question that is very much related to this one.

Comment: Rubio, as a non-native speaker who moved to the US for college, I've had first-hand experience with misunderstanding what people meant when they called something "interesting" - perhaps that's why I can relate. In my language, interesting is good, and calling someone interesting is a compliment. @AIQ point taken - I was trying to strike a balance. The OP is new to the site, and their level of English based on word & phrase choice made me feel like they could use a bit of extra help. Wasn't aware of the other similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking because you've been in a situation where someone told you that your name was interesting? What they probably meant - assuming they were friendly - was that they thought your name was unique or uncommon, compared to more familiar names like "John" or "Mary".